# Related field not working - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo

I've inherited `res.partner` and added two fields to it.

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[(('mina', 'Mina'))])
    origen = fields.Char(string="Origen")
    destino = fields.Char(string="Destino")
```

I want show these fields, on another model, like this:

```
class routes(models.Model):
    _name = 'routes'

    partner = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
    orig_ = fields.Char(related="partner.origen", string="Origen", store=True)
    dest_ = fields.Char(related="partner.destino", string="Destino", store=True)
```

These fields are being showed on form view, but they doesn't let me select anything, it's just a `Char` type field, like its not related, what could it be the reason?

Comment: Please update your question with *view.xml* file. It seems everything good in .py side. Might be helpful for future https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-related-field-work-in-odoo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related fields are readonly fields, that's why you cannot edit them. If you want to edit them, just use normal Char field. If you want these fields have default values, use default attribute

```
orig_ = fields.Char(string="Origen", default=lambda self: self.partner.origen)
dest_ = fields.Char(string="Destino", default=lambda self: self.partner.destino)
```